# MongoDb Architecture for Level Of Seperation

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongodb-query

What will be the ideal architecture for maintaining degree of separation between users in MongoDb?
For example I have a collection "users" with the following 3 documents(This architecture can be wrong. I expect a correct architecture in answer please):

```
{
    _id: ObjectID('abc'),
    name: 'abc',
    friends: ['def', 'xyz']
},
{
    _id: ObjectID('def'),
    name: 'def',
    friends: ['ghi', 'xyz']
},
{
    _id: ObjectID('ghi'),
    name: 'ghi',
    friends: ['jkl', 'xyz']
}
```

I want to query the path of separation between users. So please help me out with a right architecture for the same or a right mongodb query.

```
abc->is friend of->def->is friend of->ghi
```

Comment: You're trying to get transitive relations (edges) of your data 'nodes', which kinda calls for the usage of a Graph Database. Is MongoDB a requirement or are you free to choose the db technology?

Comment: Agree. Graph DB should be the right solution. You can try Neo4j or Orient DB.

Comment: I have to use MongoDb. I know Graph database is the right thing to do this but can someone think of best possible way in mongo?

Comment: do we need to iterate all array fields?

Comment: There are [possibilities](https://www.compose.io/articles/graph-data-with-mongodb/) to store graph like data in MongoDB. Essentially you just put the "nodes" (which are the people in your case) and the "edges" (which are the uni directional friendship relations of those people in your case) in separate collections. I can't think of a efficient way to query a whole path from root to leaf though. You then have to query the next step on the path one at a time from the application layer...

Comment: Thank you @SimonZ. That was very helpful.